# open() function not accepting single argument or string type argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to just simply read file into my program but the `open()` function is not accepting `"r"` or any sting as argument, I don't know how it is possible.

Comment: I can see from your profile that you have a habit of posting images when asking questions. My friendly advice would be to not do this and instead simply post the code in the question body (indenting it by 4 spaces also formats it for you.)

Comment: thanks for the advise I'm quite new!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.open` isn't the function you should be using. Just call `open` directly which uses the built-in.

[From the docs on `os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open):

> Note: This function is intended for low-level I/O. For normal usage, use the built-in function `open()`, which returns a file object with `read()` and `write()` methods (and many more). To wrap a file descriptor in a file object, use `fdopen()`.

Comment: Thanks !!It was such a simple thing!!

Comment: @AgrawalAnkush it was indeed. In general always try and head to the Python docs for authoritative advice on things like these, you'll be surprised how many times the answer can be found there :-)

Answer (score 0):

just like Jim said : try below

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
f.read()
```

if you want to read the file line by line then use a loop :

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
for line in f:
    print line
```